# How do I rearrange $E[\log p(X, Y|\Theta)|X, \Theta^{(i - 1)}]$ to $\int_{y \in \Upsilon} \log p(X, y|\Theta)f(y|X, \Theta^{(i - 1)})dy$?

Tags: probability, integration, stochastic-integrals

Equation (2) from [here](http://lasa.epfl.ch/teaching/lectures/ML_Phd/Notes/GP-GMM.pdf). Is there a formula for this? Also what does it mean if only the bottom part of the integral is specified, and how does $y \in \Upsilon$ even work in an integral?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it just the definition of expected value value $E[\cdot]$ with respect to a continuous probability density function $f$? <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value> ....

Comment: Looks like you're right, I still don't completely understand it yet though. What does $\int_{y \in \Upsilon}$ mean? where does $f()$ come from? Why did the $Y$ change to a lowercase $y$?

Comment: Have you encountered integration before?